# Vimeo.player events not triggering on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vimeo

I have a Vimeo Video player element on my page, and Im trying to use a click event to trigger some other events, only thing is the event does not trigger on mobile. Im trying to trigger on the play event.

HTML

```
<div data-vimeo-id="232290519" data-vimeo-responsive="1" id="salesvideo" class="hidden-xs"></div>
<div data-vimeo-id="232290536" data-vimeo-responsive="1" id="salesvideo" class="visible-xs-block"></div>
```

JS

```
var salesvideoplayer = new Vimeo.Player('salesvideo');

salesvideoplayer.play().then(function () {
        salesvideoplayer.on('pause', function (data) {
            $('.slider-header-campaign1').html("hello");
            $(".hidden-content").css("display", "block");
            $(".prepackaged__card-body").css("display", "none");
            $(".footer").css("display", "block");
            $("#need-help").css("display", "block");
        });
    });
```